# Determine SD-card quality

Tags: debian, sd-card

A Raspberry Pi uses an SD-card for the storage of the OS. Over time the SD-card "wears out" due to reaching its maximum number of write-cycles.

I've been using these boards for some time now and found that when the SD-card is worn the machine will crash or hang. This usually happens when least expected and it will take some time (me trying several re-installs) before I realize the card has deceased and needs replacement. This is very frustrating.

Is there a tool that lets me analyse an SD-card (preferably while in use) so I can anticipate the card's wear and prepare a replacement? And how would I need to use it?

The cards are formatted with `f2fs` and used with Debian Linux.

**EDIT**  Given @Doug's answer is there a way to see this coming? What I'm thinking about is perhaps keep a checksum of a set of files and periodically check those to see if a checksum has changed.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer no.  With SD cards the required data is not collected.

SD cards and SSD are similar in technology but differ in the way they both are typically used therefore an SD card does not have the  performance and health software that an SSD would have.